# ReactNative App completely crashing when receiving a file that's not a Picture(Like a video or audio)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, express, expo

My code works well for images, but whenever I choose a video or audio the app completely crashes on the on handleDownload. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, Switch, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { shareAsync, shareSync } from 'expo-sharing';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

const File = ({ name, serverData }) => {
  const [sync, setSync] = useState(false);
  console.log('File name:', name);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(serverData.url);
  const [port, setPort] = useState(serverData.port);

  const handleDownload = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(`Downloading ${name}`);
      // Check or request permissions using MediaLibrary
      const permissions = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (permissions.status !== 'granted') {
        console.error('Permission to access media library was denied');
        return;
      }
      const response = await fetch(`http://${url}:${port}/download`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ filename: name }),
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
  
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = async () => {
        const base64data = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        // Use a persistent directory for downloads
        const downloadsDirectory = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}Download/`;
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(downloadsDirectory, { intermediates: true });
        const localUri = downloadsDirectory + encodeURIComponent(name);
        await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(localUri, base64data, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
  
        // Save the file to the device's 'Download' folder
        let album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Download');
        if (!album) {
          album = await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Download', null, false);
        }
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localUri);
        await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
        console.log(`File saved to the Downloads folder`);
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Download error:', error.message);
    }
  };
  
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    // Example implementation of delete functionality
    try {
      console.log(`Deleting ${name}`);
      const response = await fetch('http://${url}:${port}/delete', {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ filename: name }),
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      console.log(`File ${name} deleted successfully`);
      // Perform any additional cleanup or state updates needed after deletion
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Delete error:', error.message);
    }
  };


  const handleSyncChange = () => {
    setSync(!sync);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.fileContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.fileName}>{name}</Text>
      <Button title="Download" onPress={handleDownload} />
      <Button title="Delete" onPress={handleDelete} />
      <View style={styles.syncContainer}>
        <Text>Sync</Text>
        <Switch value={sync} onValueChange={handleSyncChange} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fileContainer: {
    // Add your styles here
  },
  fileName: {
    // Add your styles here
  },
  syncContainer: {
    // Add your styles here
  },
});

export default File;
```

I've tried using different requests methods like FileSystem.downloadAsync but those didn't seem to work as I expected it and where storing files at 147 bytes.